# combine fuse holder and connector

Tags: connector, fuses, fuse-holders

Is it possible to make a fuse holder combined with a contact to use on a pcb?

I'm looking to save space on my board and to integrate the fuse with the contact instead of placing them on a line on the board. Does it even exist?

Just an example to make it alittle bit more clear.
A fuse box like this: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/eaton/BK-HTB-24I-R/283-2711-ND/954291
and maybe a connector head like this: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/S2B-PH-SM4-TB-LF-SN/455-1749-1-ND/926846

Comment: What's wrong with using a PCB mounted fuse holder?

Comment: How about an in-line fuse holder in the cable leading to the connector? Such as one of https://www.mouser.com/Circuit-Protection/Fuse-Holders/Fuse-Holder/_/N-axfrp?P=1z0z385

Comment: @Puff: I think the point is that the OP doesn't know they exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up something like *fuse clips*.  The same goes for cylindrical batteries.  The clips are thru-hole parts that mount right on your board.  The board provides the mechanical support.  I have used such fuse and battery holders quite a bit.

If the fuses handle high voltage, then you may not want the conducting parts exposed where user could touch them or things could accidentally contact them.  There are plastic covers for exactly this purpose.

Check out the Keystone product line.  Here is one example:

[image]

Comment: +1 Depending on the product though you may also want to add a tie down. I have seen these arrive with the fuse floating around inside the enclosure.

Comment: @Trevor: For something low mass like a 5 mm or 3AG fuse, these clips hold them quite solidly.  I've had devices using these clips pass shake table tests.  Batteries are heavier, and some means of keeping them in the clip is a good idea.  The slip-on plastic protective covers for fuses do come off easily.  We put a tie wrap around the fuse and cover in production.  That has also passed shake table tests.  The user has to cut the tie wrap to replace the fuse, but then it's on them.

Comment: Yup, I agree the good ones have some beefy springs. Still, it's sometimes unbelievable what comes back... For a non-user serviceable fuse, a non-removable component is more reliable, or a panel/case mounted one if it is user changeable. If the user has to open the box to change the fuse it's generaly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can search for pcb mount fuse holder or smd type fuse holder.
just see the available components from mouser
https://www.mouser.in/Circuit-Protection/Fuse-Holders/Fuse-Holder/_/N-axfrp?P=1z0z80nZ1z0z7pt

[image].
[image]